# Unable to connect to locally running apache drill from JAVA

Tags: apache-drill

I get the following error

```
Running com.rms.importnumbermatching.TestExecuteDrillQuery SLF4J: Failed to       load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation` (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:31010 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270) at
```

I have the following code

```
    `Class.forName("org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver");
      conn =          DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:31010");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();`
```

I have the following dependency in POM

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
            <artifactId>drill-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>`

I cannot seem to connect to drill, the second line fails. giving the error "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:31010"

What am i missing here?

Comment: clean your maven project properly,  it should work.

Comment: Running com.rms.importnumbermatching.TestExecuteDrillQuery
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:31010
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at com.rms.importnumbermatching.ExecuteDrillQuery.ExecuteCountQuery(Ex..

Comment: i get above error , i am out of ideas on whats wrong..

Comment: Edit your question with this error so that others can also see this

Comment: Did you try drill-jdbc-all jar?

Comment: have you added jdbc jar in in 3rd party.?

Comment: Thanks all. Adding the jdbc-all did the trick